# Nature / street sounds recording

Tags: audio

I would like to record 2 or more channels of good audio (up to 15-20 kHz) with Raspberry Pi for nature / street sound capture.

What hardware do I need?

Does naked Raspi contain ANY ADC or sound capture?

**UPDATE**

Don't even think about any shopping advices or other offtopics. I will Google for items myself, but any terminology and/or architecture and/or chipset notes would be appreciated.

Comment: The Pi has no usable ADC.  The rest of the question seems to be asking for shopping advice which may be off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Audio has two common ways to get into the Pi: I2S and USB.

- I2S is a standard digital interface between a codec and a processor.  This is probably more complicated than you are looking for, but there are off the shelf boards that have a codec designed for plugging into the Pi.  Likely will require you solder a header onto the Pi.
- USB.  Generally any Linux supported microphone or webcam will work.  Look at RasPi compatible hardware lists for more info.  USB microphones are often higher quality and higher price.